# Getting the screen size of iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-6-plus

I have an application which is compatible with iPhone4 upto iPhone 6. For displaying the UI on multiple devices I am using:

```
CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
```

and depending on the height and width returned, I am identifying the iPhone type and displaying a relevant image. The problem is when I run this code on the iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 Plus *simulator* it is still returning 568px as the screen height, the same as the iPhone 5.

How do I get the screen height of iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus please?

Comment: You did not set the correct launch images of the 4.7 and 5.5 devices. thus you app is running in scaled mode.

Comment: Your code gets grandfathered in to the older screen size when you don't have either a launch image of the appropriate size, or a launchscreen interface file. If you add those to the project it will see the appropriate screen size. This question has already been asked here several times.

Comment: Not very sure about this,but as  long as your app is supported i.e if you have place launch screens for iPhone 6 and +, placing @3x imaged will automatically loaded based on device(similar to retina images) .SO all you have to do is place the image name with@3x suffix and proper resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a XIB file named as LaunchScreen.xib. and set this as your launch screen file under "App icons and launch images" tab.

Or you can simply add launch images for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus. It will resolve your issue.